# How to halt consuming messages in an AMQP for a certain period of time (where time is not fixed)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I am trying to achieve the following scenario in my application:

1. When my application is up, the message from the incoming exchange should be consumed by the incoming queue.
2. If any exception/error occurs, the messages are directed to the DeadLetter Queue.
3. When downtime is going on for my application (I don't want to consume messages during that time), I am redirecting the messages to the ParkingLot Queue.
4. When downtime is over, I want to first consume the message from the ParkingLot Queue, and then start consuming messages normally using Incoming Queue.

[image]

My question is: Can these scenarios be implemented? Here, mainly I am talking about step 4. If yes, can someone please point me in the correct direction?

My second question is: Is it the correct way to achieve this scenario? Or is there a better way to achieve it?

Code added:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${com.rabbitmq.queueName}", id="msgId")
    @RabbitListener(queues = "${com.rabbitmq.parkingQueueName}", id="parkingId")
    public void consumeMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            log.info("Received message: {}",new String(message.getBody()));
            
            //check if the application is down
            if(val) {
                registry.getListenerContainer("msgId").stop();
                rabbitTemplate.send(rabbitMQConfig.getExchange(), rabbitMQConfig.getParkingRoutingKey(), message);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            rabbitTemplate.send(rabbitMQConfig.getDeadLetterExchange(), rabbitMQConfig.getDeadLetterRoutingKey(), message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each `@RabbitListener` an `id` attribute.

Then use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to control the containers' lifecycles.

```
registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop();
```

and

```
registry.getListenerContainer(id).start();
```

You can put both `@RabbitListener` annotations on the same method.

Comment: Thank you @Gary for your response. I have tried something in the code mentioned in the edited message. But all the messages are going to the deal letter queue. Can you let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe add some logging to the catch block to see what exception is thrown? Also, you shouldn't stop the container on the listener thread - it will cause a delay "waiting for listeners to finish"; run `stop()` on another thread.